# I want upload files to AWS S3 bucket in Spring Boot web application

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-s3-client

If you run the code below, the following error occurred. I want to know the solution. I want to see a sample of how to do the AWS S3 configuration part. Source code

```java
S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.create();
UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = UploadFileRequest.builder()
                                 .putObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket(BUCKET).key(downloadFileName))
                                 .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
                                 .source(Paths.get(filePath_Extract))
                                 .build();
FileUpload upload = transferManager.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest);
// Wait for the transfer to complete
upload.completionFuture().join();
```

Error

```java
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider
.
.
.


SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
    , EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
    , WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set.

    To use Sso related properties in the '112903851907_CREWODS' profile
    , the 'sso' service module must be on the class path.
    , ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set.
    , InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to load credentials from IMDS.
```

I tried

```java
S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.create();
UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = UploadFileRequest.builder()
                                 .putObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket(BUCKET).key(downloadFileName))
                                 .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
                                 .source(Paths.get(filePath_Extract))
                                 .build();
FileUpload upload = transferManager.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest);
// Wait for the transfer to complete
upload.completionFuture().join();
```

I expect the local files to be uploaded to the AWS S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

To make requests to AWS S3, you must supply AWS temporary credentials. You can achieve this in few different ways:

- default credential provider chain (recommended).
- specific credential provider or provider chain (or create your own).
- supply the temporary credentials yourself in code.

More information on how SDK is looking for temporary credentials can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default

Here is example code:

```java
S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient
        .builder()
        .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
        .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1)
        .build();

S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager
        .builder()
        .s3Client(s3AsyncClient)
        .build();
```

You can also choose the provider yourself depending on the profile with which the application works. Read the documentation and look at the `AwsCredentialsProvider` interface and see what implementations it has.
Choose the one you need. If it still doesn't work, then there is a problem with the AWS credentials / profile configuration.

Comment: If this answer best solved your issue, then consider marking it as correct to help guide others with the same issue in the future.